# Nyquist plot - is my system stable?

Tags: control-system, stability, nyquist-plot

I am working on a balance controller for a robot. I have obtained a transfer function between the robots motor voltage and the robot pitch angle.
$$G= \frac{ -5.893e05 s^4 - 7.71e08 s^3 - 1.435e11 s^2 - 2.566e12 s - 7.683e09}{s^7 + 2418 s^6 + 1.317e06 s^5 + 1.977e08 s^4 + 1.312e10 s^3 + 1.796e11 s^2 - 9.658e11 s - 1.525e13}$$

The bode plot is:-
[image]

The system has poles and zeroes

[image]

As you can see, there is a pole on the RHP which means the system is unstable. There are no zeroes in the RHP. I plotted the Nyquist plot of the open loop system:-

[image]

According to the Nyquist stability criteria, I need \$N=P-Z = 1-0 = 1 \$ counter-clock-wise encirclements of -1 in order for the system to be stable. And this is not the case. In believe I can fix this if I add a PI-term to my system. I add a negative gain of \$K_p = -2 \$ and an I-term \$C_i(s)\frac{0.1s + 1}{0.1s} \$, so now my open loop transfer function is:
$$G_{ol,2}=K_pC_i(s)G(s) = -2 \cdot \frac{0.1s+1}{0.1s} \cdot G(s) $$
If I plot the Nyquist plot of the open loop system now I obtain:-

[image]

And it looks like there is one encirclement of -1, which should mean that the system is stable. I also found the step response for the closed loop system with unit feedback \$G_{cl} = \frac{G_{ol,2}}{1+G_{ol,2}} \$ and got this:-

[image]

To me, the system looks stable, but I just want to be absolute sure if what I have done is the correct procedure. Also, as you can see in the step response I have a steady state error of 45% or so. Is there a way to fix this, maybe adding another term to my controller?

Comment: "*I plotted the nyquist plot of the **closed** loop system*". The actual plot is that of the open loop system, which will predict if the resulting unity feedback closed loop system will be stable or not. What did you actually plot?

Comment: @AJN I now realize that I am supposed to use the Nyquist plot for the **open** loop system, and not the closed system. Thanks for giving me a heads up.

Comment: With the new plot plotted, is your original question answered ?

Comment: @AJN I think I will edit the entire question, and ask something else, since my initial question was based on falsehood.

Comment: "*I have a steady state error of 45% or so. Is there a way to fix this, maybe adding another term to my controller?*" Simulate the step response for 1000s and see if the steady state error is still 45%. I think the pole of integrator you introduced is slowing down the final settling response. Plot root locus to get an idea. What did you base the zero of the controller on ?

Comment: @AJN I edited the question once again and inserted the bode plot of the open loop transfer function. As you can see, at around 10 rad/s is the maximum magnitude. I placed the zero at \$\omega_i = 10 rad/s \$ and from there got \$\tau_i = \frac{1}{\omega_i} =0.1  \$. I did as you suggested and plotted the step response for 1000s, and it turns out that after 500 seconds the system has a massive spike and becomes unstable.

Comment: "*after 500 seconds the system has a massive spike*" What software are you using ? Can you post the specific code for the step response ? It may be a numerical processing artifact. Repeat the step response with small time step. If matlab, something like `step(closedloopsys, linspace(0, 1000, 100000)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123090/discussion-between-ajn-and-carl).